# Javascript replace content innerhtml on click with integrated PHP tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to replace the content of a DIV once the button inside that DIV is clicked, (basically replacing the button, which retreives a PHP variable:

```
<div id="buttonholder">
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:publish('<?php echo $id;?>');">Publish</a>
</div>
```

I am trying to replace it with an unpublish button after a post is published (when the button above is clicked):

```
function publish(status){
document.getElementById("buttonholder").innerHTML = '<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:publish('<?php echo $id;?>');">Unpublish</a>';
}
```

It does not work however ... What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: *It does not work however* That tells us nothing. What is the error message in the browser's console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code syntax is wrong. Use like below.

```
function publish(status){
document.getElementById("buttonholder").innerHTML = '<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:publish(\'<?php echo $id;?>\');">Unpublish</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you RajivRisi ! Worked perfectly ! Yes I had trouble with the ' apostrophes

Answer (score 0):

Add a button id and then do:

```
$(function() {
    $("#buttonId").click(function() {
        $("#buttonHolder").html(" html to replace with ");
    });
});
```

Also you can use the `$("#buttonHolder").html(" html to replace with ");` instruction in your onClick function as well.

Comment: There's no jQuery in his question title or original code so you shouldn't recommend a solution that relies on it.

Comment: It's an exercise of imagination

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, but it does not work ... I think it is the mess of all those apostrophes " and ' and that PHP block, it breaks everything ...